# How to explode an array from a string?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I want to create an array from this string, stored in database:

```
$string = '"2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1"';
$id_values = explode('=> "', $string);
foreach($id_values as $id => $value)
{
    $value_to_print .= '<img src="images/item_values/'.$id.'.gif"> - '.$value.'';
}

echo $value_to_print;
```

Manually defining the array works as expected:

```
$id_values = array("2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1");
```

Comment: *I've got this string that comes from a table in my database:* Is the string in this format saved in your db?!

Comment: is it you who saves the string in the database? maybe save it as a `serialize($array)` instead?

Comment: one script in another page gets those arrays from a xml file and import it into the table, then whenever i need those arrays in a page of my website I can use that info of that table

Comment: Yes thats me who saves the string. I'll search on google about this serialize($array) and post a comment asap ty

Comment: @Ghost That would have been my next comment after OP wrote: `yes exactly.... –  user3050478 3 mins ago` You just have to up 2x * around the "why" :)

Comment: @Rizier123 so much for databases :-( thats why table columns are there for, should have used `image_id` or whatever name

Comment: @Ghost If I would have a country: abusing a database would be illegal! (OP: Please normalize your db!)

Comment: That's always very frustrating whenever you inherit of some code/data you have not choice but to deal with and you come ask here and you get comments asking to chose the damn whole thing. I agree, it's ugly, hard to use and it would be much better to normalize DB, but maybe the OP doesn't get the choice to work with that ? Maybe there's a whole codebase relying on this data format, which would make it an even bigger issue, but also even longer to solve...

Comment: @Bartdude judging from his comments, I'd rather say that op is not fully aware/fully not aware of what he's doing. If indeed he inherited a huge codebase and is not able to deal with it, it may be time that some people tell him that good practices *exist*

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier > Indeed, and as I said I totally agree that besides helping him with the current question, it is wiser to also explain the best-practices, also to avoid further issues. Right now the issue might be solvable but if he continues like that he may indeed face some unsolvable issues, or big performance issues, and then be forced to rewrite a whole codebase. That is however very frustrating anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$id` isn't going to be the number from the original string - it will create a new one.

You could try this:

```
$string = '"2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1"';
$id_values = array();
$bits = explode(",", $string);
foreach ($bits as $b) {
    $bobs = explode(" => ", $b);
    $id_values[$bobs[0]] = $bobs[1];
}
foreach($id_values as $id => $value){
    $value_to_print .= '<img src="images/item_values/'.$id.'.gif"> - '.$value.'';
}
```

That's untested but it should be fine.

In the future, use `json_encode` and `json_decode` to store and retrieve arrays.

Note: You probably want to get rid of the quotes too - just add

$b = str_replace('"', '', $b);

on the line before `$bobs = explode(" => ", $b);`

Comment: That worked for me, but I didn't understand the code tho... guess thats not ur fault

Answer (score 5):

It might be a better idea to save it in a better/more usable format, maybe using [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php):

The serialize function returns a string. You can then save that string in your database, at the same place you save your other string.

say this is your array:

```
$a = [2258=>"here",2259=>"then"];
$s = serialize($a);
// save the content of $s to your database
```

then, to get an array from the produced string:

```
// $s is the string from your database
$a = unserialize($s);
```

Comment: where would tat array go in my database?

Comment: please understand that `serialize()` returns a simple *string*, the same format as your original string. just save it to your database the same way you did with the other one

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
$value_to_print = '';
$string = '"2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1"';

$array = explode(',',$string);

foreach($array as $data){
       $indata = explode('=>',$data);           
       $value_to_print .= '<img src="images/item_values/'.trim($indata[0]).'.gif"> - '.trim($indata[1]).'';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will help you to decode the given string array correctly. Here  you need to explore first by **','** and then followed by **'=>'**

```
$string = '"2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1"';

$value_to_print = "";

 $items = explode(",",$string);
foreach($items as $item)
{
  $pair = explode("=>",str_replace('"','',$item));
   $value_to_print .= '<img src="images/item_values/'.$pair[0].'.gif"> - '.$pair[1].'';
}

echo $value_to_print;
```

Here **str_replace** function can be used to remove the quotes

Comment: this is already in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29748693/576767) from [grim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/662645/grim)

Comment: yes. but it was not loading in ma system. just now loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '"2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1"';   
$arr = array();

// split into key-val pairs
foreach(explode(',', $string) as $pair) {
    // we use a regular expression in case the input does not 
    // have spaces surrounding the "hash-rocket"
    // we also use str_replace to remove quotes
    $key_val = preg_split("/[\s*]=>[\s*]/", str_replace('"', "", $pair));
    // ensure pair is well formed
    if (count($key_val) === 2) {
        $arr[$key_val[0]] = $key_val[1];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [2148]=>
  string(2) "50"
  [2050]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2403]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: I would do that if i had to work with data from a legacy database - otherwise I would use serialize as recommended by @félix-gagnon-grenier.  However that would mean that you cannot query on this data and changing your DB structure might be a better alternative.

Answer (score -1):

I would just use eval instead. Basically make make it into a PHP expression and then use eval. Try this.

```
$string = '"2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1"';
$string = 'return array(' . $string . ');';
$array = eval($string);

$value_to_print = '';

foreach($array as $id => $value){
    $value_to_print .= '<img src="images/item_values/'.$id.'.gif"> - '.$value.'';
}

echo $value_to_print;
```

Comment: What if the input contains user generated data? Oh sh*t.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the Below code Snipet It will work.
[image]

```
<?php
    $string = '"2148" => "50","2050" => "2","2403" => "1"';
    $string = str_replace('"','',$string);

    $arrayList = explode(",",$string);
    $imageData = array();

    foreach($arrayList as $id=>$values){
        $arrayElemenets = explode(" => ",$values);
        $imageData[$arrayElemenets[0]] = $arrayElemenets[1];
    }

    $value_to_print = "";
    foreach($imageData as $id => $value){
        $value_to_print .= '<img src="images/item_values/'.$id.'.gif"> - '.$value.'';
    }

    echo $value_to_print;
?>
```

Comment: this is already in [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29748693/576767) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29748986/576767) answers, from [grim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/662645/grim) and [Talifhani](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418355/talifhani-luvhengo)